# REST-based Cryptotokenkit implementation

Tags: macos, cryptotokenkit

I have my cryptographic keys and certificates made available via a custom REST service (the private keys don't actually export, they can just do cryptographic operations using the private keys behind the REST service and the result is returned).

I want these objects to show up in my macos keychain and I want to be able to use those objects to sign data.

My understanding is I need to create a cryptotokenkit implementation to do this. However, I see that the only way to load such an implementation is when a card is physically inserted into the machine.

Is there a way to load such a token without needing a physical device inserted into the computer?

Comment: "Tokens are physical devices that can be built in to the system, located on attached hardware (like a smart card), or accessible through a network connection."
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cryptotokenkit
So this _should_ not be an issue. Maybe this has been improved since you asked the question? I'd love to know if it's still an issue for you, thanks!